# How to import okhttp in a standard java program?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am trying to import the okhttp package in a java program, but I have not been able to find how to do it.

For now, I have downloaded the package on my computer (from the following git hub link : https://github.com/square/okhttp) but I do not understand how to import the package in my program.

Any suggestion on how to use this package?

Comment: add okhttp jar to your project build path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Download Dependency

You can download the jar file from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.7.5).

[image: download jar]

## Add to Project Classpath

Then you need to add it to your classpath.

### Shell

If you're compiling from the terminal place your okhttp.jar file in the same directory as your Java class.  You can then run the following command

```
javac -cp okhttp-2.7.5.jar MyClass.java
```

> You need to replace okhttp-2.7.5.jar with the actual name of the okhttp jar, and replace MyClass.java with the actually name of your Java file

### Eclipse

1. Right click on project
2. Build Path...
3. Configure Build Path....
4. Add External Jar
5. Select the jar file

[image: right click]
[image: add external jar]

> The method outlined above is the simplest way to add dependencies to a project.  However, there are specific technologies such as *Ant*, *Maven*, and *Gradle* which allow you to include dependencies through XML or other DSL's

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Sorry about the lack of detail, the thing is that I am not using any particular tools. I am programming using gvim and am compiling in the linux terminal. And for the program, for now I do not have a specific one either, I am just trying to make okhttp works for a project. I am completely new to Java programming so I did not knew that eclipse was a thing, I will try it right away !

Comment: If you are using VIM just use the command I posted. Download the okhttp jar file, then us the -cp flag when you run javac.

Comment: @Antoine see my updated answer about adding jar files to classpath from commandline

Comment: okhttp3 link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp